# Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.QuerySet'> while aggregating data

Tags: python, django

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/pyramid/login/')
def defaulters_report(request):
    template = 'private/admin/report_defaulters.html'
    queryset = list(TreeNode.objects.all())
    for x in queryset:
        x.d = x.debt
    defaulters = TreeNode.objects.filter(id__in=([x.id for x in queryset if x.d > 0]))
    context = dict()
    unpaid_purepro = defaulters[0].annuities.all()
    for x in list(defaulters)[1:]:
        unpaid_purepro = unpaid_purepro | x.annuities.all()
    unpaid_purepro = unpaid_purepro.filter(expected_date__lt=timezone.now())
    context['total'] = unpaid_purepro.all().aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum']
    return render(request, template, context)
```

When I try to get value of unpaid_purepro - I get the error as in title of question. Final error of view is:

```
Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000)
```

Where I am wrong?

In other words: for each TreeNode FilterPayment with last expected_date should be selected and TreeNodes should be ordered by their's payment__expected_date

**UPD:**

models.py:

```
class TreeNode(MPTTModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'участник'
        verbose_name_plural = 'участники'

    # account for auth

    account = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='аккаунт', related_name='treenode')

    @property
    def debt(self):
        ...

    @property
    def last_payment(self):
        return self.annuities.last()

    @property
    def pay_progress(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.annuities.exclude(fact_date=None).aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum'],
                             self.annuities.aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum'])


class FilterPayment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'взнос за фильтр'
        verbose_name_plural = 'взносы за фильтр'

    expected_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='ожидаемая дата')
    fact_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='фактическая дата', null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='сумма')
    client = models.ForeignKey(TreeNode, related_name='annuities', verbose_name='клиент')

    CASH = 1
    TERMINAL = 2

    METHOD_CHOICES = (
        (CASH, "Cash"),
        (TERMINAL, "Mobilnik")
    )
    method = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=METHOD_CHOICES, default=1)
```

Comment: Can you update question and add code of your models?

Comment: Can you add code of `debt` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error, because some of generated SQL queries are too large for SQLite. If you need sum of `annuities` with past `expected_date` of `treenodes` with positive `debt`, you can try this:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/pyramid/login/')
def defaulters_report(request):
    template = 'private/admin/report_defaulters.html'
    context = {}

    context['total'] = TreeNode.objects.filter(
        debt__gt=0,
        annuities__expected_date__lt=timezone.now()
    ).aggregate(total=Sum('annuities__total'))['total']

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Documentation:

- [Executing queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/)
- [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/)